# Goodsync S3 Empty Secret Access Key (AKA Hacking you Linux Goodsync configurations file)

Tags: backup, authentication, amazon-s3, debian-wheezy

I'm trying to use Goodsync from Linux (Wheezy). I have set up a backup to S3 (see below) but I keep getting the error  Empty Secret Access Key.

```
=== Job === test:<
'file:///testgsynclocal/' <-> 's3://A*****************Q@s3.amazonaws.com/testbucketname1234567890'
161653 Connected to /testgsynclocal: unix-disk
161653 Empty Secret Access Key (Password)
```

It doesn't matter which switch I use to try and put the Secret Access Key into the TIX file. I have tried:

```
/n2=Fh******************************************nId 
/k2=Fh******************************************nId 
/password2=Fh******************************************nId 
/pwd-encr-2=Fh******************************************nId
```

None of them set the Secret Access Key. It does work from the Goodsync GUI on my OSX to the S3 share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even the Goodsyncs team couldn't tell me the proper was to do it using the Linux `gsync` tools. Their documentation is really weak for Linux. I think `gsync` (the linux variation of Goodsync) is still pretty beta.

Their suggestion was to set it up on the OSX or Windows GUI and export the files out. So the steps were...

1. Install the Goodsync GUI on either flavor OS (OSX or Windows)
2. Create all the backups as necessary. If possible, use network paths to things (sftp, smb, afp, etc) instead of hardcoded file paths (since the file paths will not match your actual Linux box where you want this TIX file to run) - that way you don't have to hack the TIX file at the end.
3. Set up everything for the jobs (including auto-run settings, usernames, password, etc) just how you want them to be on the linux box. Be fast, because if you set up autorun it will keep trying to start the backups...which prevents you from making further changes or exporting the files. Sometimes turning 'auto-off' in the main Windows GUI prevents this. Sometimes not.
4. Find the 'export all jobs' action in the GUI. In OSX this is Main `Goodsync` button (next to the Apple icon).
5. Save the file somewhere. It will save as a TIX ('TIX' not 'TIC') file extension. TIX is directly compatible with the Linux Goodsync install.
6. Find the `jobs-groups-options.tix` file on the Linux box. On wheezy this is in `~/.goodsync` directory.
7. Replace the `jobs-groups-options.tix` file with your TIX file.

NOTE: You can still use the gsync commands on this file normally. I.e. you can change the left-side file path via:

```
./gsync job-update JobName /n1=file:///dir1/dir2/
```

That will change the left-side filepath in the event you couldn't do it initially in the GUI (on the non-linux system).

Comment: The filename on windows was different than the linux filename I had to replace - `~/.goodsync/jobs-groups-options.tix` is the linux filename, whereas the windows export is called `goodsync_job.tix`. I was able to directly edit the file to change paths as required.